# Understanding QGraphicsScene in Qt

Tags: qt

I am trying to understand the basics of Qt. After going through some posts, I came to know that `ui_mainwindow.h` gets created by `UIC tool` and that `ui_mainwindow.h` contains the information about my form/ui that I created.

In my `GUI`, I have taken a pushbutton and a graphics view. I want a simple image (which I am creating inside the program itself) gets displayed in the `graphicsView`. I am trying to do it with two ways (for learning purpose):

- I can write the code inside `on_pushButton_clicked()`(i.e. the slot of my push_button).
- I am trying to put the image from the `main()`

**Problem:** I am done with the first method. I used the following lines of code inside `on_pushButton_clicked()` and it worked.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{    
    //Display image in the graphics viewer
    Mat img(200,200, CV_8UC3, Scalar(255,0,0));
    QImage image( img.data, img.cols, img.rows, img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888 );

    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    QGraphicsPixmapItem* item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    scene->addItem(item);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
}
```

Now, I want to do the similar thing from the `main()`. To do that, now my `main()` looks like following:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

//For image
#include <QImage>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
//#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

//OPENCV Headers
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    //Display image in the graphics viewer
    Mat img(200,200, CV_8UC3, Scalar(255,0,0));
    QImage image( img.data, img.cols, img.rows, img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888 );

    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    QGraphicsPixmapItem* item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    scene->addItem(item);
    w.ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The above code written inside the `main()` works if I put  `#include "ui_mainwindow.h"` in `main.cpp`. But if I comment `#include "ui_mainwindow.h"` and  `w.ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);` then, it throws error for the `QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();`.

Error is `main.cpp:32: error: allocation of incomplete type 'QGraphicsScene' QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();`

**QUESTIONS:** Why is the connection between `QGraphicsScene` and `"ui_mainwindow.h"`. I understand that I need `"ui_mainwindow.h"` for the line `w.ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);` becasue there I am using my `ui` but I don't understand the need for `QGraphicsScene`.

Comment: You need to include `QGraphicsScene`: `#include <QGraphicsScene>`. It is included in `ui_mainwindow.h`, that is why you don't get that error when you include that header.

Comment: @thuga: thanks, it was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If You want to draw only static image better use just `QLabel` and set in some image

```
QImage *image = new QImage (":/prefix/image/vl.jpg" );
QLabel *magelab = new QLabel();
magelab->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*image));
```

Generaly `QGraphicsScene` better using with connection `QGraphicsView.` That is mean `QGraphicsView` set some object (scene) from `QGraphicsScene` just like:

```
class SomeObject : public QGraphicsView 
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Schemat(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    QGraphicsScene *scene;


};
```

and source

```
Schemat::Schemat( QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(parent)
{

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    this->setScene(scene);
   // to Your scene You can add some image for example
    scene->addPixmap(SOME_PIXMAP)

}
```

Then You create main window and add with Your `QGraphicsView`, for example as some part `QGroupBox`

```
void MainWindow::SetupSchemat()
{
    schema = new Schemat();
    QGroupBox *schbox;
    QHBoxLayout *hschbox;
    schbox = new QGroupBox(this); 
    hschbox = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    schbox->setTitle("SomeScene");
    hschbox->addWidget(schema); //add scene to layout
    schbox->setLayout(hschbox);
}
```

`QGraphicsScene` is like **some part of Your MainWindow** on which you can make some animation, You can something draw. `QGraphicsScene` is more better to using if You want use animation not only static image it supplies more option to manipulate image (ex scaling, catch mouse click, manage via cordinates others object), and other object each should be animate or just display. To `QGraphicsScene` You can add some **QGraphicsItem** in turn each `QGraphicsItem` can moving onto `QGraphicsScene` with particular conditions defined erly or in flow. Together `QGraphicsView`, `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsItem` can created animation or just image in some part Your main window.

Also nice explained You will find here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmSs2mNGh9I